# Intersection of superlevel set of polynomials

Tags: cv.complex-variables, polynomials

Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be complex polynomials with complex coefficients and $c > 0$. Can we find polynomial $P_3$ and $c’>0$ such that

> $\{z \in \mathbb C : |P_1(z)| \geq c\} \cap \{ z \in \mathbb C : |P_2(z)| \geq c\}= \{ z \in \mathbb C : |P_3(z)| \geq c’\}$

holds?

It seems like this is either trivially false or very hard problem. I don’t have much idea. Any suggestion or reference is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right: this is trivially false.

Let $P_1(z)=z^2,\; P_2(z)=(z-a)^2$, and $c=1$. Then the boundaries of the first two level sets are circles of radius $1$,
and choosing an appropriate $a$ you can make them cross at any given angle.

On the other hand the boundary of the set in the RHS is a polynomial lemniscate,
and it is clear that it cannot cross itself under any angle except $\pi/n$ where
$n$ is an integer. (This is a general local property of level sets of harmonic functions,
which is easy to prove.)

Comment: I didn’t understand your comment in the bracket because $|P_3|$ need not be harmonic. Also can we at least find polynomial $P_3$ whose superlevel set is close (may be in Housdorff metric sense) to intersection of superlevel sets of $P_1$ and $P_2$?

Comment: @Mayuresh: $\log|P|$ is harmonic (away from the zeros of $P$) and has the same level lines.